# How to read specific fields from binary file using numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, file-io

I have a binary file that I am reading containing an array of a data type:

```
dt_particles = np.dtype([('id', np.int64), \
                         ('x', np.float32), \
                         ('y', np.float32), \
                         ('z', np.float32), \
                         ('vx', np.float32), \
                         ('vy', np.float32), \
                         ('vz', np.float32)])
```

I can read the entire array of `dt_particles` elements using:

```
numpy.rec.fromfile(FILE_OBJ, dtype=dt_particles, shape=NUM_ELEMENTS)
```

How do I read only `id` field from the binary file and skip other fields?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used `fromfile` much, but I doubt if it is possible to read selected fields.  Clearly it is using the `dtype` to determine the layout and spacing of the elements.  There's no parameter like `usecols` in `genfromtxt` to read selected fields or columns.  And no way to say, read 8 bytes, and skip the next 6*4 bytes.

Just read the whole thing and select the desired field.  It's got to read the whole file anyways.

Comment: Ok, my only concern was that I am using large data files and I wanted to skip over as much unneeded processing as I could. If numpy reads the whole file anyways, it wouldn't make much of a difference.

Comment: Doing a `read 8 bytes`, `seek forward 24`, repeat to the end of the file, will be a lot slower than read the file in 1028 byte chunks (or larger) and processing those.  If you limit the number of items then it doesn't have to read the whole file; but any one field is distributed through the file.